# Do matrices over noncommutative division rings have well-defined ranks?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

It is known that the row and column rank of any matrix over a field are the same and their common value is simply called the rank of the matrix.

Now, for any $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ with entries in a noncommutative division ring $D$, one could consider the following four ranks:

1. The dimension of the left $D$-submodule of $D^m$ generated by the columns of $A$.
2. The dimension of the right $D$-submodule of $D^m$ generated by the columns of $A$.
3. The dimension of the left $D$-submodule of $D^n$ generated by the rows of $A$.
4. The dimension of the right $D$-submodule of $D^n$ generated by the rows of $A$.

Are the above four ranks then always the same? If not, then there should be a counterexample for $D$ the Hamiltonian quaternions.

Comment: I don't know your answer, but it would seem to me only 2,3 would be acceptable candidates for the rank.  In contrast, 1,4 would seem to related to the transpose $A^T$.

Comment: I imagine we'll find out these values all have to coincide for division rings, but if it didn't work, the quaternions would not be my first suspect. I'd suspect a division ring that wasn't isomorphic to its opposite ring, and one that wasn't finite dimensional over a field.

Comment: If $D$ is finite dimensional over a field $F$, I think it's still true that $\dim V_F/\dim D_F=\dim V_D$. It seems like this lets you compare dimension across the sides.